# Getting an Enum or Static Property from Generic Reference Type <T>

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0

So if there is an `enum` property in a `class` called `Bar`, why can't I access the `enum` property or any `static` property of `type` `<T>` in this situation. I am implicitly declaring that `<T>` is of `type` `Bar`. Just wanted to know if it's simply a limitation of Generics or the `enum` `type` itself.

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Bar
{
     public Foo()
     {
         // This obviously works
         var car = Bar.Cars.Honda;
         var name = Bar.Name;  

         // Why can't I do this ?
         var car2 = T.Cars.Toyota;
         var name2 = T.Name;
     }
}

public class Bar
{
     public static string Name { get; set; }
     public enum Cars
     {
         Honda,
         Toyota
     };
}
```

**UPDATED**

In **@Frederik Gheysels's** answer, it's mentioned that if I have a `class` that is simply derived from `Bar` that I wouldn't have access to the `enum` or any `static` of the `base`. That is not correct, this compiles and works.

```
public class Foo : Bar
{
    public Foo()
    {
        // This all works
        var address = this.Address;
        var car = Foo.Cars.Honda;
        var name = Foo.Name;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public enum Cars
    {
        Honda,
        Toyota
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you *want* to be able to do that? What's the use case here?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196661/calling-a-static-method-on-a-generic-type-parameter

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704201/what-is-the-best-way-to-override-enums)?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, the use case, well there is none. Someone asked me why this is not possible. The only thing I could come up with, is that it's simply a limitation of generics. I just wanted to see if there was a better answer.

Comment: @Gabe: it's worth bearing in mind that the right answer to "why is X not possible?" is often "because it's not useful enough to merit the resources to design, specify, implement and test" - which includes "it's fundamentally broken as an idea" :)

Answer (score 1):

your `Cars` enum, is a nested type inside class `Bar`.  It is not a member property / method of `Bar`.
Therefore, it is not possible.

Cars is just a nested type of Bar.  When you create another class, which derives from Bar, lets call it `Bar2`, you will not have access to `Bar2.Cars` neither, since that type will not be created.   Nested types are not instance members, and are thus not inherited.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question why is this not possible.

Comment: It *is* a member of Bar - a type is a kind of member.

Comment: Yes, but specific to Bar.  An inherited type of Bar, which will be allowed as a Generic parameter for T, will not have an <inheritedtype>.Cars type.

Comment: If I have a `class` `Bar2` that simply derives from `Bar` I **would** have access to the `enum` or `static` properties. Check my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

A potential workaround is to allow `Foo<T>` to inherit from `Bar` to expose the static members. To access the static member `Name`, you need to provide a virtual accessor as [discussed here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/ade8bd54-100a-402b-8419-5b08817578e2/).

```cs
public class Foo<T> : Bar where T : Bar
{
    public Foo()
    {
        // This obviously works
        var car = Bar.Cars.Honda;
        var name = Bar.Name;

        // use base class for enum accessor ?
        var car2 = Foo<T>.Cars.Toyota;
        var name2 = Foo<T>.Name;

        default(T).Accessor = "test"; // static member access
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public enum Cars { Honda, Toyota };
    public virtual string Accessor
    {
        get { return Name; }
        set { Name = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: But `Foo` may not be a `Bar`. It most likely isn't, if you consider any collection type generics.