# Extension and enum type

Tags: c#-4.0, enums, extension-methods

I am trying to add Extension method to Enum type but the code below fail. The compiler gives error on line `StoreType.GetAllItems` How to add extension method to Enum type?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllItems<T>(this Enum value)
        {
            foreach (object item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            {
                yield return (T)item;
            }
        }


    }

    class Program
    {

        [Flags]
        public enum StoreType
        {
            Paypal = 1,
            Plimus = 2,
            Other = 3
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
           StoreType.GetAllItems //Fail here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call GetAllItems on a value, not a type:

```
StoreType.Paypal.GetAllItems()
```

But wouldn't it be better to not make it an extension method en declare it as:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllItems<T>()
    {
        foreach (object item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            yield return (T)item;
        }
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var allEnumItems = EnumExtensions.GetAllItems<StoreType>()
}
```

Or even:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof (StoreType));
Enum.GetNames(typeof (StoreType));
```

After which you can use Enum.TryParse(...) to parse the names back to the enums, which I think is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You see the compiler error because you *cannot* override default c# **enum**, according [to this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704201/what-is-the-best-way-to-override-enums) try to override your enum this way, by adding your method to a custom class:

```
public class MyEnum
{
    public static readonly MyEnum A = new MyEnum("A");
    public static readonly MyEnum B = new MyEnum("B");
    public static readonly MyEnum C = new MyEnum("C");
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllItems<T>(this Enum value)
    {
        foreach (object item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            yield return (T)item;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    protected MyEnum(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class MyDerivedEnum : MyEnum
{
    public static readonly MyDerivedEnum D = new MyDerivedEnum("D");

    private MyDerivedEnum(string value)
        : base(value)
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyEnum blah = MyEnum.A;
        System.Console.WriteLine(blah);
        blah = MyDerivedEnum.D;
        System.Console.WriteLine(blah);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that would be a class with pseudo extensions. It might look like this:

Usage:

```
List<HttpStatusCode> list = EnumUtils<HttpStatusCode>.ToList();

Dictionary<int, HttpStatusCode> map = EnumUtils<HttpStatusCode>.ToDictionary();
```

The pseudo extension class:

```
/// <summary>Pseudo extension class for enumerations</summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEnum">Enumeration type</typeparam>
public class EnumUtils<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    public static List<TEnum> ToList()
    {
        var enumType = typeof(TEnum);

        return enumType.IsEnum
            ? enumType.GetEnumValues().OfType<TEnum>().ToList()
            : throw new ArgumentException($"{enumType.Name} is not enum");
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, TEnum> ToDictionary()
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(TEnum);

        return enumType.IsEnum
            ? enumType.GetEnumValues().OfType<TEnum>().ToDictionary(
                e => Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), e.ToString()) as Enum), 
                e => e)
            : throw new ArgumentException($"{enumType.Name} is not enum");
    }
}
```

Enjoy!