# Display the angles of each joint of the skeleton in kinect c#

Tags: kinect

How to display the angles of Kinect skeleton joints?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192476/kinect-sideways-skeleton-tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the programm you are looking for:

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.SkeletonBasics
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Ports;
    using System.Threading;
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using Microsoft.Kinect;
    using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Fusion;
    using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

    public class Angles
    {
    public double AngleBetweenTwoVectors(Vector3D vectorA, Vector3D vectorB)
        {
            double dotProduct;
            vectorA.Normalize();
            vectorB.Normalize();
            dotProduct = Vector3D.DotProduct(vectorA, vectorB);

            return (double)Math.Acos(dotProduct)/Math.PI*180;
        }

        public byte[] GetVector(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            Vector3D ShoulderCenter = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position.Z);
            Vector3D RightShoulder = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.Z);
            Vector3D LeftShoulder = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.Z);
            Vector3D RightElbow = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Z);
            Vector3D LeftElbow = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Z);
            Vector3D RightWrist = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.Z);
            Vector3D LeftWrist = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.Z);
            Vector3D UpVector = new Vector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

            double AngleRightElbow = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(RightElbow - RightShoulder, RightElbow - RightWrist);
            double AngleRightShoulder = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(UpVector, RightShoulder - RightElbow);
            double AngleLeftElbow = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(LeftElbow - LeftShoulder, LeftElbow - LeftWrist);
            double AngleLeftShoulder = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(UpVector, LeftShoulder - LeftElbow);


            byte[] Angles = {Convert.ToByte(AngleRightElbow), Convert.ToByte(AngleRightShoulder),Convert.ToByte(AngleLeftElbow),Convert.ToByte(AngleLeftShoulder)};
            return Angles;
        }
}

    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SerialPort ArduinoPort;
        /// Width of output drawing
        private const float RenderWidth = 640.0f;

        /// Height of our output drawing
        private const float RenderHeight = 480.0f;

        /// Thickness of drawn joint lines
        private const double JointThickness = 3;

        /// Thickness of body center ellipse
        private const double BodyCenterThickness = 10;

        /// Thickness of clip edge rectangles
        private const double ClipBoundsThickness = 10;

        /// Brush used to draw skeleton center point
        private readonly Brush centerPointBrush = Brushes.Blue;

        /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently tracked
        private readonly Brush trackedJointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68));

        /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently inferred
        private readonly Brush inferredJointBrush = Brushes.Yellow;

        /// Pen used for drawing bones that are currently tracked
        private readonly Pen trackedBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 6);

        /// Pen used for drawing bones that are currently inferred
        private readonly Pen inferredBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1);

        /// Active Kinect sensor
        private KinectSensor sensor;

        /// Drawing group for skeleton rendering output
        private DrawingGroup drawingGroup;

        /// Drawing image that we will display
        private DrawingImage imageSource;

        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void RenderClippedEdges(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Bottom))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
            }

            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Top))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(0, 0, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
            }

            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Left))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(0, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));
            }

            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Right))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(RenderWidth - ClipBoundsThickness, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));
            }
        }

        private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Create the drawing group we'll use for drawing
            this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

            // Create an image source that we can use in our image control
            this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);

            // Display the drawing using our image control
            Image.Source = this.imageSource;

            // Look through all sensors and start the first connected one.
            // This requires that a Kinect is connected at the time of app startup.
            // To make your app robust against plug/unplug, 
            // it is recommended to use KinectSensorChooser provided in Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit (See components in Toolkit Browser).
            foreach (var potentialSensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
            {
                if (potentialSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
                {
                    this.sensor = potentialSensor;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                // Turn on the skeleton stream to receive skeleton frames
                this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();

                // Add an event handler to be called whenever there is new color frame data
                this.sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += this.SensorSkeletonFrameReady;

                // Start the sensor!
                try
                {
                    this.sensor.Start();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    this.sensor = null;
                }
            }

            if (null == this.sensor)
            {
                this.statusBarText.Text = Properties.Resources.NoKinectReady;
            }
        }

        private void WindowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                //ArduinoPort.Close();
                this.sensor.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {

            Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (skeletonFrame != null)
                {
                    skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

                }
            }

            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {
                // Draw a transparent background to set the render size
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));

                if (skeletons.Length != 0)
                {
                    foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                    {
                        RenderClippedEdges(skel, dc);

                        if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                        {
                            this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);
                            Angles MyAngles = new Angles();
                            byte[] ReadyAngles = MyAngles.GetVector(skel);
                            RightElbow.Text = ReadyAngles[0].ToString();
                            RightShoulder.Text = ReadyAngles[1].ToString();
                            LeftElbow.Text = ReadyAngles[2].ToString();
                            LeftShoulder.Text = ReadyAngles[3].ToString();
                            byte[] SequenceStart = {255};

                            if (ArduinoPort.IsOpen)
                            {
                                ArduinoPort.Write(SequenceStart,0,1);
                                ArduinoPort.Write(ReadyAngles, 0, 4);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                        {
                            dc.DrawEllipse(
                            this.centerPointBrush,
                            null,
                            this.SkeletonPointToScreen(skel.Position),
                            BodyCenterThickness,
                            BodyCenterThickness);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // prevent drawing outside of our render area
                this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));
            }
        }

        private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            // Render Torso
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Spine);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Spine, JointType.HipCenter);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight);

            // Left Arm
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft);

            // Right Arm
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight);

            // Left Leg
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft);

            // Right Leg
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight);


            // Render Joints
            foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
            {
                Brush drawBrush = null;

                if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
                {
                    drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;                    
                }
                else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
                {
                    drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;                    
                }

                if (drawBrush != null)
                {
                    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint.Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
                }
            }
        }

        private Point SkeletonPointToScreen(SkeletonPoint skelpoint)
        {
            // Convert point to depth space.  
            // We are not using depth directly, but we do want the points in our 640x480 output resolution.
            DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skelpoint, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
            return new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
        }

        private void DrawBone(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext, JointType jointType0, JointType jointType1)
        {
            Joint joint0 = skeleton.Joints[jointType0];
            Joint joint1 = skeleton.Joints[jointType1];

            // If we can't find either of these joints, exit
            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked ||
                joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Don't draw if both points are inferred
            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred &&
                joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
            {
                return;
            }

            // We assume all drawn bones are inferred unless BOTH joints are tracked
            Pen drawPen = this.inferredBonePen;
            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                drawPen = this.trackedBonePen;
            }

            drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint0.Position), this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint1.Position));
        }

        private void CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                if (this.checkBoxSeatedMode.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
                {
                    this.sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Default;
                }
            }
        }

        private void CheckBoxConnectArduino(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.checkArduinoConnected.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                string MyCOM = "COM10";
                ArduinoPort = new SerialPort(MyCOM, 9600);
                ArduinoPort.Open();
            }
            else {
                ArduinoPort.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.SkeletonBasics.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Skeleton Basics" Height="735" Width="770" Loaded="WindowLoaded" Closing="WindowClosing">

    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumGreyBrush" Color="#ff6e6e6e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectPurpleBrush" Color="#ff52318f"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectBlueBrush" Color="#ff00BCF2"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="SquareCheckBox" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                                <Grid x:Name="SquareCheckBoxChecked">
                                    <Image x:Name="CheckedNormal" Source="Images\CheckedNormal.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Image x:Name="CheckedHover" Source="Images\CheckedHover.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="SquareCheckBoxUnchecked" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Image x:Name="UncheckedNormal" Source="Images\UncheckedNormal.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Image x:Name="UncheckedHover" Source="Images\UncheckedHover.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="SquareCheckBoxText" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource KinectPurpleBrush}" FontSize="15"  Margin="9,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxChecked"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxUnchecked"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="CheckedNormal"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="UncheckedNormal"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="CheckedHover"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="UncheckedHover"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource KinectBlueBrush}" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxText"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Name="layoutGrid" Margin="10 0 10 0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 0 0 20">
            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="Images\Logo.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="32" Width="81" Margin="0 10 0 5"/>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0 0 -1 0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="{StaticResource MediumGreyBrush}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18">Skeleton Basics</TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Images\Status.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 5"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Name="Image" Width="640" Height="480"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SquareCheckBox}" Content="Connect Arduino" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 10 10 10" Name="checkArduinoConnected" Checked="CheckBoxConnectArduino" Unchecked="CheckBoxConnectArduino"/>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SquareCheckBox}" Content="Seated Mode" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 10 10 10" Name="checkBoxSeatedMode" Checked="CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged" Unchecked="CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged"/>
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="statusBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="White" Foreground="{StaticResource MediumGreyBrush}">
            <StatusBarItem Padding="0 0 0 10">
                <TextBlock Name="statusBarText" Margin="-1 0 0 0">Click 'Seated' to change skeletal pipeline type!</TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
        <TextBox Name="RightShoulder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="150,12,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox Name="RightElbow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="250,12,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox Name="LeftShoulder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="350,12,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox Name="LeftElbow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="450,12,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Of course you can not use the images, but that is not necessary. If this doesn't work right away just send me your e-mail and I will send you the complete source code :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try Kinect Angles @ http://drenton72.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/kinect-angles-v2-4/

Answer (score 2):

I created Kinect Angles all I do is read the X,Y positions of the joints and then work out difference between the two positions as you would with vectors (just subtract one vector from the other one). Then I use simple trig to work out the angle of the vector. My Kinect Angles is open source so you should be able to figure it out from my source code.