# how measure elbow angle between arm reaching to horizontal to end of the arm action

Tags: c#, kinect, angle

I want to calculate elbow angle between arm reaching the horizontal and the end of the arm action when throwing a ball using skeletal data acquired from Kinect. Please answer me, anyone knows how to extract only the skeletal frames of arm reaching the horizontal and the end of the arm action and how to calculate an angle between them.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is too broad for the format of StackOverflow. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). If you have a piece of code and a specific problem you can ask here how to solve this specific problem. But people here will not be inclined to write half a novel to answer a broad question. Good luck :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974178/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-2-vectors-in-3d-space-given-a-preset-function , http://www.analyzemath.com/stepbystep_mathworksheets/vectors/vector3D_angle.html

Comment: And this even gives you code for kinect: [Display the angles of each joint of the skeleton in kinect c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11061287/982149)

Comment: Thank you very much