# C# instantiate enum from another one

Tags: c#, enums

I have a web reference that has an enum in it.

```
WebService.WebEnum.Member1
WebService.WebEnum.Member2
WebService.WebEnum.Member3
```

etc.

Is there any way to create another enum based on WebEnum ? I have been pulling hair for hours on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean create a new enum that inherits from WebEnum? The answer is no I'm afraid

Comment: @n8wrl, that's it. I guess i'll have to find something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum "Inheritance"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance)

Comment: C# and Java aren't as good with "enumerations" today as Pascal was 35 years ago.  And C++ "enums" absolutely suck (the reason so many people simply use "#define MYNUM" or "const mynum").  No, you can't really do it.  Java arguably comes closest: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can't use inheritance on enums.

However, you can achieve something that feels similar by using static member properties for a class (instead of the enum). This class can then be extended via inheritance.

```
public class WebEnum
{
     protected WebEnum(int value)
     {
         ...
     }

     private static WebEnum _member1 = new WebEnum(1);

     public static WebEnum Member1
     {
         get { return _member1; }
     }
}
```

Then you can extend with

```
public class OtherWebEnums : WebEnums
{
     private static WebEnum _member4 = new WebEnum(4);

     public static WebEnum Member4
     {
          get { return _member4; }
     }
}
```

Disclaimer: In terms of a design, I bet some people would be upset to see it as it probably breaks numerous object oriented design rules... But it should serve purpose...

Comment: Some rules deserve to be broken :)

Comment: The one thing I would say about this is that it's now a reference type and not a value type, which can have unintended consequences. But as value types can't be inherited this is the only way to go. Just make sure the type is immutable and declare an implicit conversion to int, and most of the concerns with it being a reference type go away.

Comment: @KeithS - Great tips! A private/protected constructor to control instantiation is advised too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [design-time T4 text templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) to generate an enum based on another one.

(You will have to set the assembly name to be appropriate for your WebService enum.)

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)WebService\bin\Debug\WebService.Dll" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
enum GeneratedEnum
{
<# foreach(var member in Enum.GetValues(typeof(WebService.WebEnum))){ #>
     <#= member #>,
<# } #>
    AdditionalMember1,
    AdditionalMember2
}
```

The `GeneratedEnum` type will be created at compile time, and will look like this:

```
enum GeneratedEnum
{
    Member1,
    Member2,
    Member3,
    AdditionalMember1,
    AdditionalMember2
}
```