# Enum inheritance - C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enum “Inheritance”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance)

I'm trying to do something like this

```
enum BaseEnum
{ }

enum SubgEnum1 : BaseEnum
{ }

enum SubEnum2 : BaseEnum
{ }
```

is it possible to do in any way!?

Because what I really need is to declare a property of type BaseEnum and the values are from SubEnum1 or SubEnum2!

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/757762/558486

Comment: You can use classes with public consts instead of enums

Comment: Is this way gonna provide saving the class' static constant as a string in Database?!