# Enum property in parent class should change inside derive class

Tags: c#, .net

If I have in my Parent class property ConditionStatus of datatype ConditionEnum like

```
interface IArticle
{
    ConditionEnum ConditionStatus {get; set;}
}
```

enum is represent like `ConditionEnum {New, Used};`

I'm wonder how can I change this `ConditionEnum` in child class so that `ArticleA` which implements `IArticle` can have enum like `ConditionEnum {Red, Blue, Yellow};`
and `ArticleB` which also implements `IArticle` have `enum` like `ConditionEnum {Point, Comma, Slash};` I think you've got an idea.

How would you do it?

Comment: Damn, I had typed in a comment on your previous question, "Are you willing to make Article generic?", and when I clicked "Add Comment" I was informed that you'd deleted the question! Ah, well, life is tough ...  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your interface generic:

```
public interface IArticle<T> where T : struct
{
    T ConditionStatus { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleA : IArticle<ColorEnum>
{
    public ColorEnum ConditionStatus { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleB : IArticle<PunctuationEnum>
{
    public PunctuationEnum ConditionStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you can't enforce that `T` is an enum... and you do need to specify which enum your implementation will use. It's not entirely clear whether that's going to help you or not, but it's about all there is...

Comment: You could also use where T : struct, IConvertible. Shame that your where T : Enum hack hasn't made it to the compiler yet.

Comment: As usual, jon skeet laying down the knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

Since [`enums` can't derive from other `enum` types or interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance), it's almost impossible. What you describe seems polymorphism to me. But AMAIK, you can't apply polymorphism to enums.

Answer (score 0):

1. That's not a parent class, but an interface.
2. You can have an `enum` inside a class, you'd refer to it as `ClassA.ConditionEnum.*`:

.

```
class MyClass : IArticle {
    public enum ConditionEnum { Red, Blue, Yellow };

    public ConditionEnum myenum;
}

MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.myenum = MyClass.ConditionEnum.Red;
```