# Factory design pattern using enums and inheritence

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums, factory

I have a conceptual problem. I'd like to use the design pattern factory, using an enum to know what type of object to create. But when it comes to inherit in another assembly, I'm stick with my enum ...

Let me explain a case :

I'm creating a Framework for multiple projects that manage fruits.

I create an interface `IFruit` implemented by an abstract class `Fruit`, from which will inherit `Strawberry`, `Apple` and `Pear`.

I create an enum `FruitTypes` which contains `Strawberry`, `Apple` and `Pear`.

I create `FruitFactory` with a virtual method :
`GiveMeANewFruit(FruitTypes newFruit)` which returns an `IFruit`.

Everything's ok.

I send my Framework all over the world and someone in our spanish plant needs to manage also bananas.

He'll create `Banana` class that inherits `Fruit`.

He'll create a `SpanishFruitFactory` that will inherit from `FruitFactory` and redefine virtual method `GiveMeANewFruit`, here is the code that could be in that method :

```
Public Override IFruit GiveMeANewFruit(FruitTypes newFruit)
{
    if (newFruit == FruitTypes.Banana)
        return new Banana();
    else
        return base.GiveMeANewFruit(newFruit);
}
```

But hey, here's the problem. I know languages like C# don't permit to inherit enums. So, my guy cannot add the `Banana` value to the `FruitTypes` enum.

So, what would be the best pattern to replace the enum so I can give the outside world the capability to add new object types to my concept ?

Knowing that I DO NOT want to have anything outside source code (no XML file, nor database nor anything else providing the types list).

Do you have any advice ?

Comment: It is not java, and use MEF.

Comment: Here is an introduction to MEF: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/kreekman/TechDays-2010-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-MEF-through-Silverlight

Comment: @clcto Simply saying "use MEF" with absolutely no indication of what you're referring to or how it may be relevant isn't exactly helpful. I'm really not sure what the Mount Everest Foundation has to do with this.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/757815/1693085 - or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4042826/1693085 - Could these maybe do it??

Comment: @Sierramike I'd use the second link in John Bustos' comment

Comment: @clcto : OMG, I know MEF, but it's somewhat overkill for what I want to achieve. Also, their file and directory structure imposed for MEF to work makes it non friendly, I want to keep it simple to use for other developers. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @John Bustos : I think your second link, as says Pacane, is the most usefull, I wish you had put that as an answer so I could mark it accepted ! Thanks !

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, it seems like the best solution to this was already answered very well in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4042826/1693085). Glad it worked for you!!

Comment: I just posted it as a solution, but wish the original poster had... His solution is written nicer than I ever would have managed :p Either way, glad it gave you what you're looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best replacement is `static class`. That's the way I'm doing it in `php`.
Define `static class` with fields instead of `enum`, you can even define fields as `string` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the factory method to accept an `int`, and implement enums using classes such as these:-

```
public class FruitTypes
{
    public const int Strawberry = 1;
    public const int Apple = 2;
    public const int Pear = 3;
}

public class SpanishFruitTypes : FruitTypes
{
    public const int Banana = 4;
}
```

Example usage:-

```
factory.GiveMeANewFruit(FruitTypes.Pear)

factory.GiveMeANewFruit(SpanishFruitTypes.Banana)
```