# extending enum property from referenced dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Inside mvc4 I have model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public SomeEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

this SomeEnum is located in other dll which is referenced from my web app. I cannot change this dll (SomeEnum) but for further clarity I want to use this enum (SomeEnum) but with little extension, I want to add few more enum properties.

How this can be done?

Comment: You can see everything you need [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance)

Answer (score 3):

It cannot, basically.

All you can do is declare a new enum, perhaps with the same name in a difference namespace, perhaps with a different name:

```
namespace My.Local {
    public enum SomeEnum {
        // the originals
        A = The.Other.SomeEnum.A,
        B = The.Other.SomeEnum.B,
        C = The.Other.SomeEnum.C,
        // the extras
        D, E, F
    }
}
```