# Create custom HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes

I am developing **webapi** in **mvc4**. I want to create a class which contains Custom `HttpStatusCode` which `inherits HttpStatusCode` class. Let's suppose I have one `signup` api which require user details like Firstname, Lastname, email, password etc. Suppose user enter email `abc@abc.com` and I check if user already exists. If this email is already exists I want to return Custom HttpStatusCode. Suppose I have created **1001** `HttpStatusCode` for email already exists.

I tried some thing like this

```
return new System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult(
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                (HttpStatusCode)1001,
                new HttpError("Email is already exists.")
            )
        );
```

But I don't know is it a correct way or not. When we use `return Unauthorized();` it means it's an unauthorized access which returns **401** error code. In same way I want to create a custom response and status code. In my case suppose email id already exists then I should return something like this 
`return AlreadyExists()` which return **1001** status code. Can I implement such a way? if yes, How can I implement this? can someone please help me?

Comment: Why are you inventing HTTP status codes? What do you expect the caller/client to do when it receives your weird 1001 status code?

Comment: @BenRobinson The one implementing the API should handle the new status codes then. Custom status codes help for specific errors, imho.

Comment: When it receive 1001 it means `Email is already exists`

Comment: You should not invent your own HTTP Status codes! - Find one that fits!

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't go about inventing new HTTP status codes. I'd say that at best it violates the [Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

How about returning a response with an HTTP status code of [400 (Bad Request)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1), and an error object that contains your application's error code and message?

Alternatively, you could use the overload of `CreateErrorResponse` that takes an exception argument.

```
Request.CreateErrorResponse(
    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
    new Exception("Email already exists.")
));
```

This results in the following JSON being returned from your endpoint:

```
{
    "Message":"An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage":"Email already exists.",
    "ExceptionType":"System.Exception",
    "StackTrace":null
}
```

Comment: Thank you reply. can I inherits HttpStatusCode class in c#?

Comment: [`HttpStatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a class, it is an enumeration (so you cannot inherit from it).

Comment: If you _really_ _really_ want to then you can use the [unassigned HTTP status codes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) like 432-450 range for ClientError. You'll need to create HTTPResponseMessage and set its status code.

Answer (score 5):

> When we use `return Unauthorized()` [...] In my case suppose email id already exists then I should return something like this  `return AlreadyExists()`

`Unauthorized()` is just a method in the base controller, you can add methods to your own controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult AlreadyExists()
{
    return new System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult(
        Request.CreateErrorResponse(
            (HttpStatusCode)409,
            new HttpError("Already exists")
        )
    );
}
```

If you want to reuse it, add your own controller base class and let your controllers inherit from that:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult AlreadyExists()
    {
        return new System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult(
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                (HttpStatusCode)409,
                new HttpError("Already exists")
            )
        );
    }
}

public class RegisterController : MyApiController
{
    // ...
}
```

And like the others said, don't go invent your own HTTP status codes.

Comment: Thank you for reply. When I call `return AlreadyExists();` So it will return 409 status code right ?

Comment: Yesterday I tried `1001`. It gives me an error related to range.

Comment: That is because `1001` is not a valid HTTP status code.

Comment: If I use `409` it is not conflict. Because it is already there.

Comment: @AjayPunekar, find one that fits then... but either way, DO NOT TRY AND CREATE YOUR OWN!!

Comment: I am not opening the can of worms that is the discussion of _"Which HTTP status code is the most appropriate in situation X"_, and that was not your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster can I inherits HttpStatusCode class?

Comment: @AjayPunekar why would you want to do that? And [no, you can't, it's an enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance).