# System.Net HttpStatusCode class does not have code 422

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8.1, http-status-codes

Is there a way to handle http status code 422 gracefully. I am looking for the best practice here. I know that HttpStatusCode is an enum so what i tried is this,

```
HttpStatusCode Unprocessable = (HttpStatusCode)422;
if (Response == (HttpStatusCode)422)
```

but does not allow me to compare it. Am i doing something wrong here?

Whats the best possible way to add this status code at runtime.

Comment: thats what i am trying to ask....if i want to use 422 can i extend this enum?

Comment: No you can not, why do you want extend the ResponseCode enum. That's using standard response code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance

Comment: Is `Respose` really a `HttpStatusCode`?

Comment: @codesinchaos. Let us assume it is for now. that is not the question.

Comment: @golldy In that case I'll need to vote-to-close this as "not reproducible". Please post a working example that exhibits the problem. `(HttpStatusCode)422` works perfectly well for me, at least when using the full framework.

Answer (score 41):

I was using RestSharp which returns the server response status code in a property of type `HttStatusCode` and I needed to check for a 422 response myself but the of course the type doesn't include it. Fortunately I was still able to test using the following:

```
if(response.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)422)
{
    // Do my stuff..
}
```

Comment: Cool, glad to hear this works.  Makes sense, since enum is actually an int anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The older versions of .NET don't have this HTTP status code but some of the newer ones do ([See MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_HttpStatusCode_UnprocessableEntity)).
If you are using one of the older frameworks, then you can get the response and check the StatusCode like the following (like Nick said):

```
var httpResponseCode = Response as HttpWebResponse;
if (httpResponseCode.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)422)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If more than one action in your API can possibly return a 422, you could consider wrapping the check in an extension method like so:

```
    public static bool IsUnprocessableEntityResponse(this HttpResponseMessage message)
    {
        Requires.NotNull(message, nameof(message));

        return (int) message.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity;
    }
```

Which you can then use in your client like so:

```
    if (response.IsUnprocessableEntityResponse())
        return Response.UnprocessableEntity<Resource>();
```

While also avoiding the 422 magic number in your source code at the same time.

Comment: StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity is part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions in case anyone reads this and wonders where it is.

Comment: @Darrell, nice spot. But for me, that doesn't seem to be enough justification for adding a reference to the additional assembly.