# Call user defined Color using Color.FromName, Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string, colors

I've defined a new System.Drawing.Color;

```
Public CustomBackColor As System.Drawing.Color = Color.FromArgb(200, 4, 146)
```

Now, I have a `GlobalBackColor As String` which I wanted to become my new `CustomBackColor` Value.

My Question is, if there is any way to write CustomBackColor `System.Drawing.Color`, to the GlobalBackColor `String`. Or, to make the CustomBackColor a default System Color, so that I could define the GlobalBackColor like so: `GlobalBackColor = "CustomBackColor"`

Anyways, I would like to be able to define it like this:
`pbR001C03.BackColor = Color.FromName(GlobalBackColor)`

**EDIT:**

`pbR001C03` is a PictureBox.

In this example Example;

`Public CustomBackColor As System.Drawing.Color = Color.FromArgb(200, 4, 146)`

`Public GlobalBackColor As String`

`Public Sub Example()`

```
`GlobalBackColor = Color.FromName(CustomBackColor)`
`...`
`pbR001C03.BackColor = Color.FromName(GlobalBackColor)`
`pbR001C04.BackColor = Color.FromName(GlobalBackColor)`
`...`
```

`End Sub`

the `GlobalBackColor = Color.FromName(CustomBackColor)` does not seem to work for me. No error, just a black Color.

Comment: it `pbR001C03.BackColor = Color.FromName(GlobalBackColor)` works fine for me, when `pbR001C03` is a form control. here in your case what is `pbR001C03`? and what was the error you are getting?

Comment: I've added an example to my question ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [`Color.FromName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) like this, but you don't need to use it.
Since your `CustomBackColor` **is** of type `System.Drawing.Color` you can use it directly to any property of type `System.Drawing.Color`

```
pbR001C03.BackColor = GlobalBackColor
```

here is the method description From MSDN:

> Creates a Color structure from the specified name of a **predefined** color.

(not bold in source).

There really is no possible way to use `Color.FromName` with custom names, since it would require to extend the [`System.Drawing.KnownColors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.100).aspx) enumeration, and [extending enums is impossible in `.net`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance)

Comment: Yep, I that's true. Problem is that I need `GlobalBackColor` to be a `String`.

Comment: Why do you think you need it as a string?

Comment: Because `GlobalBackColor` is used for multiple Actions in the app source code I'm editing at the moment. Otherwise I would've obviously used the `Color`Type for `GlobalBackColor`;)

Comment: So use the color directly, Why does it have to be a string? can you provide a concrete example of a case where you can use the string but can't use the color?

Comment: f.e.
`Public Sub SolidFill(Optional BackColor As String = "Black")`
`...`
`End Sub`
If I'd use a `Color` Type for BackColor, it'd throw a Constant Expression required exception.

Comment: If you have methods like this then your design is simply **wrong**. Change these methods to get a `System.Drawing.Color` instead of a `string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am just editing this code, it's not my creation.
Thanks for the Tips though.

Comment: nothing to be sorry about, even if it was your own code, everybody is allowed to make mistakes. There really is no possible way to use Color.FromName with custom names, since it would require to extend the System.Drawing.KnownColors enum, and extending enums is impossible in .net

Comment: Aha, this is what I was trying to find out. Could you please Post this as an Answer? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include my previous comment as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik changing/extending the System.Drawing enumeration is not possible in vb.net

Comment: Whops, didn't see the answer there