# How to assign different enums to a variable in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something like this..

```
enum Birds {
    Crow,
    Sparrow,
    Hawk
}

enum Bugs {
    Ant,
    Spider,
    Scorpion
}

if (featherless == true) {
    var beast = Bugs;
} else {
    var beast = Birds;
}

string a = (beast)2.ToString();
```

I have five lines of code that works on the provided enum.  I can't imagine that I have to duplicate these five lines.. something like the above must be able to be used...   The above structure of course causes beast to be out of scope and I can't pass var as a parameter.    I know this is a headsmack moment, but I've searched and can't find a similar question.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve - or what you mean by "I can't pass var as a parameter" when you don't have any method calls to have parameters anyway...

Comment: If you mean how can I assign `Beast` to either one of the `Bug` enums, or one of the `Birds` have a look at a work around for [C#'s lack of enum inheritance / case classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/757684/314291)

Comment: `var` is not variable in type. it's variable in value.

Comment: Thanks we appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var beastType = featherless ? typeof(Bugs) : typeof(Birds);
var a = Enum.GetValues(beastType).GetValue(2).ToString();
```

Will assign `Hawk` if `featherless` is true or `Scorpion` if it's false.

**Edit 0**
Maybe this will be a better solution if you only need the name:

```
var beastType = featherless ? typeof(Bugs) : typeof(Birds);
var a = Enum.GetName(beastType, 2);
```

**Edit 1**
Maybe you can try this if you need an object for further operations:

```
var beastType = featherless ? typeof(Bugs) : typeof(Birds);
var beast = Enum.ToObject(beastType, 2);
var a = beast.ToString();
```

Comment: BRILLIANT.  Thank you soooo much.  I also really appreciate you not askign WHY I would like to do such a thing.  I'm removing the following comment from my code. /* Yes, well aware this is duplicate code but the really really smart ones at StackOverflow were more interested in critiquing a question than finding a solution to it */    Your solution does exact why my pseudo code was trying to accopmplish and more.  I'm still pissed about two lame down votes.  Totally not called for.