# What are best practices when creating an enum that holds values from other enums to ensure values are unique?

Tags: c#, enums

I have these enums:

```
public enum TestEnum1{
    Null = 0,
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

public enum TestEnum2{
    Null = 0,
    D,
    E,
    F,
}

public enum TestEnum3{
    Null = 0,
    A = TestEnum1.A,
    B = TestEnum1.B,
    D = TestEnum2.D,
}
```

In the above case, `TestEnum3` reuses values from `TestEnum 1 & 2` and some of the values will overlap. One easy way would be to make `TestEnum1.A & B = some number` but if you have many enums this seems like it could cause problems.

Comment: It doesn't really re-use them - they might have the same integer values, but they're still different.  What are you actually trying to do?  Maybe an `enum` isn't the right solution to your problem.

Comment: Replace the semicolons with commas to make it at least compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum "Inheritance"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    public enum TestEnum1{
    Null = 0,
    A,
    B,
    C,
    Last
}

    public enum TestEnum2{
    Null = 0,
    D = TestEnum1.Last,
    E,
    F,
    Last
}

public enum TestEnum3{
    Null = 0,
    A = TestEnum2.Last,
    B, 
    D,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations are value type in C#.

The code you outlined does not reuse any values you are just assigning one variable from another variable.

IMHO, the best practice would be to assign the integer value directly instead using an integer value from another Enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can already see the problems mixing enums together will cause, hence your question.
So I think the "best practice" would be... **don't do it**.

If you really must merge them somehow, you could make a struct containing one Enum or the other.

```
public struct EnumsCombined
{
     public EnumsCombined(TestEnum1 v) { Enum1 = v; }
     public EnumsCombined(TestEnum2 v) { Enum2 = v; }

     public TestEnum1? Enum1 { get; private set; }
     public TestEnum2? Enum2 { get; private set; }
}
```