# Enum Inheritance in C#

Tags: c#

I'd like to declare an enum (a bitfield) in a base class and add to that list in subclasses:

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public virtual enum Operations 
  {
    Hello = Math.Pow(2,0),
    GoodBye = Math.Pow(2,1)
  }

  public Operations ValidThingsToSay()
  {

  }
}

public class PoliteClass : BaseClass
{
  public override enum Operations : base()
  {
    ThankYou = Math.Pow(2,2),
    Please = Math.Pow(2,3)
  }
}

public class TouristClass : PoliteClass
{
  public override enum Operations : base()
  {
    WheresTheBathroom = Math.Pow(2,4),
    HowMuchIsThat = Math.Pow(2,5)
  }
}

foreach(var c in MyClasses)
 Console.WriteLine(c.ValidThingsToSay().ToString());
```

---

What's the closest clean way to do this that may still have some of the benefits of using enums (intellisense, bitfield results assignable to same type, etc.)?

> *You're going to say use constants and a list, aren't you?*

Comment: 2^3? That does not do what you think ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx

Comment: `2^2`, `2^5`?? Why *XOR* `^`? You, probably, mean `1 << 2`, `1 << 5`...

Comment: Math.Pow() is a little clearer but still won't compile, never mind that.

Comment: Sadly, just as this was closed I was just about to hit "submit" on an idea for some code that would, I think, do what you're trying to do here.

Comment: If you can edit this question away from asking for Enum inheritance, I believe I have a solution that can be adapted to achieve your end goal

Comment: @EdPlunkett - If you feel you have something useful you can always Ask and post a self-answer. Or Edit&improve this question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I put my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757684/enum-inheritance/42446664#42446664)

Comment: @toddmo Cool. I looked through the other answers there, and it looks like mine was a very slight refinement of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4042826/424129) -- I overrode `ToString` and added `explicit operator int()`