# Java enum inheritance

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [add values to enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375/add-values-to-enum)

Why enums in Java cannot inherit from other enums? Why is this implemented this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375/add-values-to-enum

Comment: I would rephrase you question.  Why enums cannot have an abstract base?

The accepted answer to the question cited by Bill explains why you cannot extend enums with other values, but it's still not clear to me why they cannot share a base implementation.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[Example stolen from here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5392073)

> Because adding elements to an enum
>   would effectively create a super
>   class, not a sub class.
>
> Consider:

```
 enum First {One, Two}   
 enum Second extends First {Three, Four}   

 First a = Second.Four;   // clearly illegal 
 Second a = First.One;  // should work
```

> This is the reverse of the way it
>   works with regular classes. I guess it
>   could be implemented that way but it
>   would be more complicated to implement
>   than it would seems, and it would
>   certainly confuse people.

Comment: Probably what you want is 
First implements MyInterface
Second implements MyInterface

Then use MyInterface for union of the two groups

Comment: Would First a = Second.One be an illegal statement?

Comment: @TimothySwan The referenced code won't be compiled, since an exception will be thrown at the `enum Second extends First {Three, Four}` line.