# Switch between two enum classes at run time in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have two enum classes:

```
public enum dog{
    Sound("barks"),
    Eat("meat"),
    Drink("water");
    private String attribute;
    private dog (String attribute){
        this.attribute = attribute; }

    public String returnAttribute(){
        return attribute;}
}
```

And

```
public enum cat{
    Sound("meows"),
    Eat("fish"),
    Drink("milk");
    private String attribute;
    private cat (String attribute){
        this.attribute = attribute; }

    public String returnAttribute(){
        return attribute;}
}
```

I would like to switch between the two enums dynamically at runtime as if it's an object(i know it isn't). So I would assign an enum "holder" for dog or cat according to a "condition" then get the attribute value i.e. enumholder.Sound.returnAttribute;
if dog it will return "barks" if cat it return "meows". Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. See, [Java enum inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884433/java-enum-inheritance)

Instead of using enums use classes and inheritance. To do what you are looking for you will need three classes, `Animal`, `Cat`, and `Dog`.

```
class Animal {
     public String getSound() {
         return "Animal sound";
     }
     // Other mehtods...
}
class Cat extends Animal {
     @Override
     public String getSound() {
         return "Meow";
     }
     // Other mehtods...
}
class Dog extends Animal {
     @Override
     public String getSound() {
         return "Bark";
     }
     // Other mehtods...
}
```

You could use these classes to get the functionality that you want.

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Animal a = new Cat();
          System.out.println(a.getSound());
          a = new Dog();
          System.out.println(a.getSound());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to just be looking for normal objects. Why do you need `enum`s?

```
class AnimalType {
    String sound, eat, drink;
}

// in some method somewhere
AnimalType cat = new AnimalType();
cat.sound = "meows";
cat.eat = "fish";
cat.drink = "milk";

AnimalType dog = new AnimalType();
dog.sound = "barks";
dog.eat = "meat";
dog.drink = "water";

// then use either cat or dog
```

Comment: nature of the beast.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though you should be modelling this as an interface that your enums inherit - the methods become what you are currently modelling as members. Something like:

```
interface Animal {
    String getFood();
    int getNumberOfLegs();
}

enum Dog implements Animal {
    POODLE, 
    GOLDEN_RETRIEVER;

    public String getFood() {
        return "dog food";
    }

    public int getNumberOfLegs() {
        return 4;
    }
}

enum Bird implements Animal {
    CANARY("seed"),
    EAGLE("meat");

    private final String food;

    Bird(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public int getNumberOfLegs() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

You can then assign a dog or cat to an `Animal` variable and it will behave correctly:

```
Animal animal;
animal = Bird.CANARY;
assertEquals("seed", animal.getFood());
animal = Dog.POODLE;
assertEquals(4, animal.getNumberOfLegs());
```

This has all the advantages of enum (fixed set of instances with the JVM working out when to construct them) while also being able to treat different sets of animals differently.

Comment: Close but I need just the enum Bird to be treated as an object not the Canary.

Answer (score 0):

If you *want* to use enum, you should do something like this instead:

```
public enum AnimalTraits {
    DOG(/*sound*/"barks",
        /*eat  */"meat",
        /*drink*/"water"),
    CAT(/*sound*/"meows",
        /*eat  */"fish",
        /*drink*/"milk");

    private final String sound;
    private final String eat;
    private final String drink;

    private AnimalTraits(String sound, String eat, String drink) {
        this.sound = sound;
        this.eat = eat;
        this.drink = drink;
    }
    public String getSound() {
        return this.sound;
    }
    public String getEat() {
        return this.eat;
    }
    public String getDrink() {
        return this.drink;
    }
}
```