# Can you add to an enum type in run-time

Tags: c#, enums, runtime

If I have an enum type:

```
public enum Sport
{
    Tennis = 0;
    Football = 1;
    Squash = 2;
    Volleyball = 3;
}
```

Can I somehow add during run-time:

```
PingPong = 4
```

Comment: you could maybe mimic this behaviour using a list or dictionary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375/add-values-to-enum

Comment: What scenario are you looking to use this in?

Comment: I have inherited code where there is an enum type that needs to expand based on user input, thereby making enum an inappropriate type, but I need a workaround in the short term.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The enum has a backing store, defaulting to int if you don't specify it. It is possible to directly assign values outside of the defined values:

```
Sport pingPong = (Sport)4;
```

Then you can check for it:

```
if (value == (Sport)4) {}
```

That is why you have the static function [`Enum.IsDefined()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) for checking if the actual value falls inside the expected values. Note that the function doesn't work for compound flag values.

```
bool isValueDefined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Sport), value);
```

EDIT: After Hans Passant's comment: You don't have to use the literal value 4. You could use anything which returns an int. For example:

```
Dictionary<int, string> AdditionalSports = new Dictionary<int, string>();
AdditionalSports.Add(4, "PingPong");

// Usages: if
if (AdditionalSports.ContainsKey(value))
{
    // Maybe do something with AdditionalSports[value], i.e. "PingPong"
}

// In a switch:
switch (value)
{
case default:
    // Since it won't be found in the enum-defined values
    if (AdditionalSports.ContainsKey(value))
    {
        // Maybe do something with AdditionalSports[value], i.e. "PingPong"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that it is at run-time because "PingPong" is being declared in the source.

Comment: It is not, the literal 4 can also be a variable.  This is the best you can get.

Comment: What would be the output of Console.WriteLine("My sport is: " + pingpong); ?

Comment: The runtime implicitely calls ToString() on pingpong. If pingpong had a defined enum value (ex. Sport.Tennis), the result is the enum value as text (i.e. "My sport is: Tennis"). If pingpong is not defined (ex. 4), it is the int value itself (i.e. "My sport is: 4"). You could use the AdditionalSports dictionary, i.e. Console.WriteLine("My sport is: " + AdditionalSports[pingpong]); to get "My sport is: PingPong".

Comment: Now you can use C# code generation feature

Answer (score 14):

Here is more Object orientated way to maybe achieve what you are trying to achieve. This solution is inspired by early Java approach to enumeration:

```
struct Sport {
    readonly int value;
    public Sport(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static implicit operator int(Sport sport) {
        return sport.value;
    }
    public static implicit operator Sport(int sport) {
        return new Sport(sport);
    }

    public const int Tennis =       0;
    public const int Football =     1;
    public const int Squash =       2;
    public const int Volleyball =   3;
}

//Usage:
Sport sport = Sport.Volleyball;
switch(sport) {
    case Sport.Squash:
        Console.WriteLine("I bounce really high");
        break;
}
Sport rugby = 5;
if (sport == rugby)
    Console.WriteLine("I am really big and eat a lot");
```

To walk through different featues of this solution.

1. It's an immutable struct that wraps up an integer value. The value is enforced immutable by `readonly` keyword.
2. The only way to create one of these structs is to call the constructor that takes the value as a parameter.
3. `implicit operator int` is there so that the structure can be used in the `switch` bock - i.e. to make the structure convertible to `int`.
4. `implicit operator Sport` is there so that you can assign integer values to the structure i.e. `Sport rugby = 5`.
5. `const` values are the sports known at compile time. They can also be used as `case` labels.

#### What I would actually do

```
public static class Sports {
    public static readonly Sport Football = new Sport("Football");
    public static readonly Sport Tennis = new Sport("Tennis");
}

public class Sport {
    public Sport(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // override object.Equals
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        var other = obj as Sport;
        if(other == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return other == this;
    }

    // override object.GetHashCode
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator == (Sport sport1, Sport sport2) {
        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(sport1, null) && Object.ReferenceEquals(sport2 , null))
            return true;

        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(sport1, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(sport2, null))
            return false;

        return sport1.Name == sport2.Name;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Sport sport1, Sport sport2) {
        return !(sport1 == sport2);
    }
}
```

This would create a value class `Sport` that has a name. Depending on your application you can extend this class to provide other attributes and methods. Having this as class gives you more flexibility as you can subclass it.

`Sports` class provides a static collection of sports that are known at compile time. This is similar to how some .NET frameworks handle named colors (i.e. WPF). Here is the usage:

```
List<Sport> sports = new List<Sport>();

sports.Add(Sports.Football);
sports.Add(Sports.Tennis);
//What if the name contains spaces?
sports.Add(new Sport("Water Polo"));

var otherSport = new Sport("Other sport");

if(sports.Contains(otherSport)) {
    //Do something
}

foreach(var sport in sports) {
    if(sport == otherSport) {
        //Do Something
    } else if(sport == Sports.Football) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Once you do this, you'd find there is actuall very little need for having an enumeration as any conditional operations on the sport type can be handled within the `Sport` class.

**EDIT** Realised that my equality operator will throw a `StackOverflowException` I always keep forgetting to write `Object.ReferenceEquals(obj,null)` instead of `obj==null`, which will recurse infinitely.

Comment: What do you think of Daniel Rose's answer?

Comment: I would chose neither. Supplementing an enumeration with stuff at runtime is a bit smelly. I would chose a consistent approach for the sports known at compile time and at run time. Example forthcoming in a little bit.

Comment: I would use `public const Sport Tennis = new Sport(0)` instead

Comment: @tster That was my first thought too. However, you can't define instances of user defined structs or classes as consts. They have to be either simple builtin types or strings. You an define those as readonly but then you would lose the ability to use them as case labels.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot modify types at runtime. You could emit new types, but modifying existing ones is not possible.

Comment: Can an emitted new type replace an existing one?

Comment: No, it can't as this would mean that you would be able to modify existing types at runtime which you can't.

Comment: Why you say you cant add values to an existing enum if the other answears are adding?

Answer (score 4):

Well yes, you can create and or alter an Enum at runtime by using the [EnumBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class,  See the sample in MSDN

```
ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");
EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum("Elevation", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));
eb.DefineLiteral("Low", 0);
eb.DefineLiteral("High", 1);
Type finished = eb.CreateType();
```

Having an enum value is, in my opinion, preferable over dictionaries or list based solution as one uses less memory and no thread side effects.

[Here are some samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137781/correct-way-to-load-assembly-find-class-and-call-run-method) on how to load the generated enum when you restart your application. I suggest you pick the one that works for you, you could use the methods provided by the [System.AddIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.addin?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace as I guess.. or use your IoC.

I use this when I need to generate data for Machine learning as having an Enum value and is preferable over lookup tables (in memory or database) as I just do not have the IO available with these large data sets.

Comment: This does not appear to be appending to a pre-existing enum list, but rather, creating one from scratch ?

Comment: @WDUK, Well you have no real way to alter an existing assembly and append a data type in it especially if the assembly is strong-named. In any case, the assembly hash will become different, and loading an assembly with the wring hash is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

If the enum can be defined at program startup, you place the enum in a separate assembly and use a bootstrapper that will recompile the enum, overwriting the old version, and then launch the actual application.  It's not the cleanest method, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the codes above but non worked and gave me bunch of errors this is how I solved it:

```
using System;
for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetValues(typeof(ButtonName)).Length; i++){
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(ButtonName)).SetValue((ButtonName)Enum.GetValues(typeof(ButtonName)).GetValue(i), i);
}
public enum ButtonName{
    Person,
    money,
    salary
}
```

this is how to value them during the runtime

[this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/loop-through-enum-values-in-c-sharp/) is where I found idea of how to go through all of them even if they aren't valued.

the most voted answer gave me some inspiration how to set only one even if I got an error from him.

hope this post helps someone

Answer (score -3):

I would create a complete Enum, with all the values you will ever need like this

```
Public enum Sport
{
    Tennis = 0;
    Football = 1;
    Squash = 2;
    Volleyball = 3;
    PingPong = 4;
    Rugby = 5;  // for example
}
```

And then keep a LIST of Invalid Sport entries, so the list would initially contain `PingPong` and `Rugby`.  Every time you access the Enum, also check with your Invalid Sports list.

Then you can simply adjust your Invalid Sports List to suit, at any stage