# Constructing an enum instance

Tags: c#

I have this enum function with some elements:

```
public enum TrackingTypeEnum
{
    None,
    Start,
    PageView,
    Foreground,
    Background,
    Push,
}
```

And I want to add some elements there, but not manually in the function, i want to use "new" command but dosn't work.

I've tried this:

```
TrackingTypeEnum Custom = new TrackingTypeEnum;
```

Any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not how enums work. If you need to add things at run time, you can't use them

Comment: okey i've seen that now... so i have to delete enum.. what can i do for do what i want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's not what enums are for- you should only use them to store **every** possible state of an object.
If you really do want to use enums, you can store those additional values in a dictionary, like it's covered in this SO answer:

[C#: can you add to an enum type in run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779743/c-can-you-add-to-an-enum-type-in-run-time)

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation, you can't use `enum` keywork in such a way. In sort, an `enum` is a list of constants you can assign values to.

Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Okey, so i must delete enum and do what? thanks!