# What is wrong with class?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner when it comes to programming Java code. I'm having a real tough time on how this class is wrong such as when I'm trying to extend the class. `public final class SeatType extends Enum`

This is my whole class:

```
package assignment;


public final class SeatType extends Enum
{

    public static final SeatType AISLE;
    public static final SeatType WINDOW;
    public static final SeatType MIDDLE;
    private static final SeatType $VALUES[];

    public static SeatType[] values()
    {
        return (SeatType[])$VALUES.clone();
    }

    public static SeatType valueOf(String name)
    {
        return (SeatType)Enum.valueOf(assignment/SeatType, name);
    }

    private SeatType(String s, int i)
    {
        super(s, i);
    }

    static 
    {
        AISLE = new SeatType("AISLE", 0);
        WINDOW = new SeatType("WINDOW", 1);
        MIDDLE = new SeatType("MIDDLE", 2);
        $VALUES = (new SeatType[] {
            AISLE, WINDOW, MIDDLE
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT:

These are the errors.

> SeatType cannot be resolved to a variable.  assignment cannot be
>   resolved to a variable. The type SeatType may not subclass Enum
>   explicitly.  The constructor Object(String, int) is undefined –

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: what is exactly wrong? what does your compiler say?

Comment: These are the errors. SeatType cannot be resolved to a variable. assignment cannot be resolved to a variable .The type SeatType may not subclass Enum explicitly. The constructor Object(String, int) is undefined

Answer (score 3):

In Java , it wont allow you to extend `Enum` explicitly.

You can create an `enum` like below :

```
    public enum Season {
      WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL; 
    }
```

According to the Java Language Specification, Each `enum` is implicitly `final` and is a subclass of `Enum`. So an `enum` already inherits from another class, making it a subclass of another class would break Java's single inheritance paradigm. An enum can, however, implement an `interface`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you extending `Enum`? In Java you cannot do this. If you want to create an enumeration class you should create a class with the definition

```
public enum SeatType {
    // your enum code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class is wrong because you're extending the `Enum` class.

You cannot extend from `Enum`. You declare an `Enum` class like that:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    AISLE,
    WINDOW,
    MIDDLE;
}
```

That will create your `Enum`. The actual usage will look like that:

```
MyEnum.valueOf("AISLE");
MyEnum.AISLE;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Java` compiler doesn't allow you to `extend` `ENUM` class. Have a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604978/subclassing-an-enum)

Also, please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to learn about using `enum`.

In this case, you can create an `enum` like,

```
public enum SeatType 
{
   WINDOW, AISLE, MIDDLE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extend `Enum` at all. You just need to use the `enum` keyword to declare an enum:

```
enum SeatType {
    ...
}
```

You don't need to have `values` and `valueOf` methods. They are inherited from `Enum`.

From the looks of it, your enum seem to have 2 fields - `i` and `s`. You should declare them as fields:

```
int i;
String s;
```

Then, write a constructor that takes an int and a string that assigns the parameters to the fields:

```
SeatType(String s, int i) {
    this.i = i;
    this.s = s;
}
```

Then, you can declare your enum values:

```
AISLE("AISLE", 0),
MIDDLE("MIDDLE", 1),
WINDOW("WINDOW", 2)
;
```

So your whole enum looks like this:

```
enum SeatType {
    AISLE("AISLE", 0),
    MIDDLE("MIDDLE", 1),
    WINDOW("WINDOW", 2)
    ;
    int i;
    String s;

    SeatType(String s, int i) {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```