# Adding values to Enum in runtime

Tags: c#

I have enum :

```
public enum ConsoleMessageType
{
    Error, Info, BackInfo, Success
}
```

### i want to add values to it in runtime, is this possible?

Comment: This has been asked before. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375/add-values-to-enum

Comment: @spakinz That is not asking the same question.  That is about inheritance, this is about amending the type at runtime.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can give the enum any value, it just wont have a name.

Comment: @Yasser Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx The "Problem statement" part is why i am asking you to state what you wand to achieve

Answer (score 1):

No. You should use a dictionary for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible.

C# is an strongly-typed language and its nature prevents from supporting such things.

Check this article about *expando objects*, which is a possible solution for your problem:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx

Comment: I dont think it is a good idea to propose a solution to an unknown problem (it might be the wrong one)

Comment: But it's a hint. My answer is _no_, but maybe _expando objects_ would be a **posible** solution (possible, I didn't say **the solution**)