# Is it possible to overwrite an enum with another class?

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to override/"hide" an enum class with another class? I am unable to edit the class without what I need to be doing failing to work, so I need to overwrite the class with another class, per se. Seeing as an enum is pretty much a final and cannot be implemented/overwritten, I and I cannot add to the class (basically what I need to do), I don't have many other options. I simply need a new class that will either overwrite, override, or add things to the enum class. Is it even possible?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: possible duplicate of [add values to enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375/add-values-to-enum)

Comment: Basically, I am trying to edit a class to do something, however, the class is an enum that cannot be edited or the client will recognize that an original class has been edited, which will just shut the client down. I need a way to make a new class that will edit the client's original class/override it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use delegation.

```
class ExtendedEnumByDelegation
{
   final MyEnum delegate;

   public void enumMethod1 ( )
   {
     delegate.enumMethod1( );
   }

   public void enumMethod2 ( )
   {
     delegate.enumMethod2( );
   }

   public void nonEnumMethod ( )
   {
      // custom stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

It is easy to use and should work for you.