# Implementing Enum Values

Tags: java, enums, implementation

I'm looking to have a base enum like this...

```
public enum SessionState {

    WAITING(true), VOTING(true), PREPARING(false), PLAYING(false), ENDING(false);

    boolean newPlayersJoin;

    private SessionState(boolean newPlayersJoin){
        this.newPlayersJoin = newPlayersJoin;
    }

    public boolean canNewPlayersJoin(){
        return newPlayersJoin;   
    }

}
```

...and then another enum with the same values (WAITING, VOTING, PREPARING, PLAYING, ENDING) but with more functions. The reason I want a base enum without the extra methods is that some of the methods depend on functions that won't be included in that jar file (multi-module project)

My other enum would look something like this

```
public enum SessionStateCopy {

    WAITING(true, ... extra values), VOTING(true, ... extra values), PREPARING(false, ... extra values), PLAYING(false, ... extra values), ENDING(false, ... extra values);

    boolean newPlayersJoin;

    private SessionStateCopy(boolean newPlayersJoin, ... extra values){
        this.newPlayersJoin = newPlayersJoin;
    }

    public boolean canNewPlayersJoin(){
        return newPlayersJoin;   
    }

    ... extra methods

}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375/add-values-to-enum

Comment: as for your requirement, i believe Enum is the wrong data type to use
what you need is an abstract class or an interface

Comment: If your question is, whether enumerators can be inherited by extending another enum: No. Enums can just implement interfaces.

Comment: Are you expecting to store state information in the enum values?  If so, that seems a little ... odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum`s in Java are implicitly `final`, so you can't inherit them from each other. I'd have the two different `enum`s, like you have in the OP, and add a couple of methods to convert between them:

```
public static SessionState convert(SessionStateCopy s) {
    return SessionState.valueOf(s.name());
}

public static SessionStateCopy convert(SessionState s) {
    return SessionStateCopy .valueOf(s.name());
}
```

Just to make sure you don't accidently add a value to one and not the other, I'd add a JUnit test to ensure this:

```
// imports snipped for clarity
public class SessionStateTest() {

    public void testMatchingMembers() {
        assertEquals("wrong number of values", SessionState.values().size(), SessionStateCopy.values().size());
        for (SessionState s: SessionState.values()) {
            assertEquals ("wrong value", s, convert(convert(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SessionStateCopy could take a SessionState in the constructor and perhaps vice versa. In that case the constants would be comparable to each other (though not in a switch). You can do something like `if (someStateCopy.copy == SessionState.WAITING) {}` if need be.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want an `enum` to extend an `enum`.

You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/java-extend-enum).

However, you can have two `enum`s implementing the same `interface`.

The one that's poorer in functionality would implements all methods but do nothing.

The other one would provide a "useful" implementation of the `interface`'s methods.

For instance:

```
enum Foo { // "extends Bar" would not compile
    FOO();
}
interface Blah {
    void meh();
}
enum Bar implements Blah {
    SOMETHING();
    public void meh() {
        // nope     
    }
}
enum GreatBar implements Blah {
    SOMETHING();
    public void meh() {
        System.out.println("I'm doing something here!");
    }
}
```