# Assigning Value of an array to Enum

Tags: c#

I wanted to assign an array value to enum.

for ex:-

```
string[] ArrayControl = new string[3] {'simple','standard','advanced'}; 

public enum Control
{
simple,
standard,
advanced
}
```

Can we apply array value to enum dinamically?

Comment: You can't assign an array to an enum. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You also can't put a string between ' ' in c#

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375/extending-an-enum-via-inheritance

Comment: for sharepoint, when we create an enum property for a visual webpart, it is displayed as a dropdown. So i needed some dynamic value to be displayed in that dropdown.

Comment: So you want to do something like this to get the values for the dropdown? `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Control))`

Comment: So will it take the values from array?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
ArrayControl = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Control));
```

This will populate `ArrayControl` with all the names of enum `Control`. You can then bind your drop down list to `ArrayControl`.

Comment: the dropdown control only takes value from enum, so i can not assign it using array.
that's why i need to assign all my values to enum first then it will come to dropdown.